# VisualHG icons doesn't appear in VS2010 solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, visualhg

Has anyone managed this problem?
All other Mercurial facilities are working fine inside VS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things to try:

- Make sure you reinstall VisualHG after installing Visual Studio 2010 (this may not be "necessary," but it's often needed for plugins of various sorts anyway).
- Make sure you have VisualHG selected as the active source control plug-in.  Go to **Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection** and make sure **VisualHG** is selected.

Comment: thanx, that was the problem

Comment: Just had the same with VS2005. Good this question has been asked and answered already.

Comment: I am not able to see the icons of VisualHg in solution explorer for VS2013. Although i have double checked the steps to be followed as given in the answer.